# python list - method instead of string

Tags: python, arrays, amazon-web-services, boto

I am playing a bit with AWS via python and boto. I am trying to get modified date for keys from AWS bucket. After that I am parsing date to 'regular' date format and try to add every value to list.

Unfortunately, when I append values to list and try to print it's results I am getting `datetime` function instead of string with date.
Code looks like this:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket')
keys = bucket.list
keys_latest_modified_date_list = []

for key in keys:
    key_latest_modified_date = boto.utils.parse_ts(key.last_modified)
    keys_latest_modified_date_list.append(key_latest_modified_date)
    print key_latest_modified_date
print keys_latest_modified_date_list
```

First `print` returns correct date:

```
2015-02-18 10:11:58
```

While second `print` gives me something like this:

```
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58)]
```

Does anyone know how to print values from list like in first `print` instead of this what I get from second one?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting confused by the `str()` output of `datetime` objects and their representation:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58)
>>> str(dt)
'2015-02-18 10:11:58'
>>> repr(dt)
'datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58)'
```

`print` calls `str` on the objects you print, but lists and other containers always show their contents with `repr()`.

You'll have to use some string formatting to process the list:

```
print ', '.join(map(str, keys_latest_modified_date_list))
```

would print a comma-separated list of datetime objects converted to strings:

```
>>> keys_latest_modified_date_list = [dt, dt]
>>> keys_latest_modified_date_list
[datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 18, 10, 11, 58)]
>>> ', '.join(map(str, keys_latest_modified_date_list))
'2015-02-18 10:11:58, 2015-02-18 10:11:58'
>>> print ', '.join(map(str, keys_latest_modified_date_list))
2015-02-18 10:11:58, 2015-02-18 10:11:58
```

Comment: Looks fine. But is there a possibility to add 'regular' string to list? I would like to make more operation on a list (ie. sorting) and 'regular' string will be more useful. Printing content of the list is not my main goal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Piotr: no, there is not. List objects are not meant to be used as end-user presentation. If you need a specific format, you need to explicitly format it yourself.

Comment: @Piotr: you'd convert the objects to strings *when you need to present the data*. If you are sorting or doing other operations with the `datetime` objects, then *keep those objects* and don't convert them to strings.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would you please give a word here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665037/concurrency-advanced-python-and-interaction-with-different-objects I would be thankful